# XMLNode children allowed by the XML Schemes associated

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I need a way to know what are the children of an XmlNode allowed by the XML Schemas associated to the XML file. Is there a simple way in C#?

I need it to implement a sort of contextual editor that suggests to the user the children allowed of the current edited XML Node.

thanks

Comment: You may try using the `XmlSchemaValidator Class` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemavalidator.aspx#Y2272. It validates XML data against XML schemas in a `push-based manner.`

Comment: So for the children it seems I can use the "getexpectedparticles". Right? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemavalidator.getexpectedparticles.aspx

Comment: Yes, as it says - `If the GetExpectedParticles method is called after the title element has been validated but before the description element has been validated, it returns an array containing a single XmlSchemaElement object representing the description element.` You may also try running the sample provided.

Comment: it has some tricks. First if the type is a sequence it returns ONLY the first element. Another trick is that you need to validate all the node front the root to the node where you want to have the allowed children

Comment: I think it works. Please post it as an answer. I'll wait a little bit for other suggestions, but I can give immediately an up vote. But I think this is the way, so at the end the right answer will be the yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using the [XmlSchemaValidator Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemavalidator.aspx#Y2272) -

It **validates XML** data against XML schemas in a `push-based manner`

See the "[GetExpectedParticles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemavalidator.getexpectedparticles.aspx)" function where for the sample it says -

> If the GetExpectedParticles method is called after the title element
>   has been validated but before the description element has been
>   validated, it returns an array containing a single XmlSchemaElement
>   object representing the description element.

You may also try running the sample provided.